# How to assign a Type to a prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a parent component:

```
// DashboardComponent.tsx

const DashboardComponent = () => {
  const {loading, error, data} = useQuery(resolvers.ReturnAllMovies);

  if (loading) return <p>loading</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error! ${error.message}</p>;

  const movies: IMovie[] = data.movies;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <DashboardMovieOverviewMenu />
      { movies.length > 0 ? <MovieOverview movies={movies} /> : null }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

And a child component:

```
// MovieOverview.tsx

const MovieOverview = (props: IMovie[]) => {
  const movies = props;

  ...
}
```

In the parent component I declare the const movies to of a type IMovie and it's an array:

[image]

In the child component I declare the prop to be of type IMovie and array:

[image]

But the parent component is showing an error:

> Type '{ movies: IMovie[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<IMovie[], keyof IMovie[]>': [Symbol.iterator], [Symbol.unscopables], map, filter, and 26 more.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `(props: IMovie[])` you're actually saying that the whole prop object is an array of IMovies.
In order to type a prop there are a couple different ways, here are two:

1. `const MovieOverview = (props: {movie:IMovie[]}) => {`
2. 

```
interface Props {
    movies: IMovie[]
}
    
const MovieOverview = (props: Props) => { 
    const movies = props;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument passed to functional components is an *object*, which contains keys corresponding to prop names, and their corresponding values. The array of movies is not the `props` argument, but nested inside as `props.movies`.

This

```
const movies = props;
```

needs to be

```
const { movies } = props;
```

or

```
const movies = props.movies
```

or use

```
const MovieOverview = ({ movies }) => {
```

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. You're suggestions work, but the issue remains that the prop type in `const MovieOverview =` still is `any`.